Why HStack doesn't allow to set 'alignment' argument?
It's simple SwiftUIView where I tried to set alignment on HStack its Showing error which I attached on screenshot.
Error is Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

HStack(alignment: .top) {
    Text("HStack1")
    Text("HStack2")
    
}


I believe the error came from somewhere else, try to narrow down by commenting out the code until you find it.

@sonle You are right. I got a solution. It was silly mistake I created SwiftUI file name HStack

Don't give layout view names to files name.
